# Different Single.php content depending on page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Backstory: I've been dealing with this website for the past 5 months. I didn't have previous experience with Wordpress, but I had some with HTML, CSS and PHP.

I have two different ways to display posts on my custom Wordpress template.

On the "Services" page, a post is loaded onto a dynamic content div by clicking on different buttons. Each button loads a different post on the same div by calling specific post ID's:

```
<a 
href="#contentBox1" 
class="dem_buttons" 
onclick="loadPage1('<?php the_permalink(361) ?>')" 
target="#contentBox1">
</a>

<div class="text-center clearfix" id="contentBox1"></div>
```

On the "Search" page there is no dynamic content div. Each search result consists on an image, the title and the excerpt of the post. The posts are acessed by clicking on their respective titles after the search results come up.

Here's the problem: If I don't include the header and the footer on single.php, the post will be loaded without styles, navigation bar and footer after clicking the title of the search result. I need to load the header and the footer on single.php because of this search page, but this means there will be a second header and footer on the dynamic content div of the "Services" page, as well.

I've tried starting single.php with:

```
<?php
if ( is_page([page id]) ) { ?> 

[single.php's content]

<?php
} else { 

get_header(); ?>
[single.php's content]
<?php get_footer(); 

} ?>
```

to no success. I've also tried out !is_page, but no luck on that either.

Please don't recommend plugins. I really need to code everything by hand. The written reason for that would be longer than this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to rearrange the parts of single.php so that it used include (or require) for showing the given post's content (named here: postcontent.php).

```
// Pseudo code

get_header()
// postcontent.php is the body of the post
include_once( postcontent.php )
get_footer()
```

This way the single.php had its header and footer, but the "Services" template could include the post's content directly:

```
// Pseudo code

// Template: Services
get_header()
// the content of the "Services" template
services_content()
// postcontent.php is the body of the post referenced
include_once( postcontent.php )
get_footer()
```

This way headers and footers are there on both pages, and there are only one header and footer on each of them.

Comment: I've tried if (is_single()){ [content with header and footer] } else { [content without header and footer] } to no avail. And yes, I am aware of the hierarchy. Determining the ID for is_single would do nothing, as the post ID is not what determinates post content.

Comment: Other idea: create a content file for the post content (that is a copy of single.php, without the header / footer, let's call it postcontent.php). Include this in single.php (between the header / footer) - so, when you call it from "Search", single.php will have the header / footer and the content. From Services call postcontent.php directly - so the header and footer are not included, only the content part. Then you do not have to have a conditional, only include a different file.

Comment: That's great lateral thinking, thanks! I'll try it when I get back to work tomorrow, and let you know if it worked. Since it most likely will, I'll mark this as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I just had to understand your case exactly. I hope it really solves the problem - if yes, then I edit my answer above, so if someone finds this question, the answer will be correct.

Comment: I had to tweak the markup a bit on the Services page to call postcontent.php instead of single.php, but it easily resolved my issues. Thanks you very much!

Comment: I'm happy that I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on the Wordpress side of all this, but could you perhaps wrap the second/first header in a div with a specific id, then give that id a style of display none? Like below:

```
HTML

<header class='header'> ..... </header>
<div id='hidden-header'>
   <header class='header'> ..... </header>
</div>


CSS

#hidden-header {
   display: none;
}
```

Let me know if that helps or not and maybe I can see if I can find something else.

Comment: I still would need some kind of conditional code to determine the page where the header would be visible or hidden. Still, neat idea.

Comment: Ah right I see - my mistake! Well I will have a look and see what I can find, no promises though sadly!

Comment: _conditional code to determine the page_

Try this:
  `<?php if ( is_page( 'PAGENAME' ) ) : ?>
  <?php endif; ?>`

Put code between the two lines, it will only show on that page. You can add multiple pages to `is_page` or you can do `!is_page` for any page but that page. Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ for more info, especially look at the user contributed notes.

Comment: Please note that is_page() is for pages - not posts. is_single() is the same function for post (and post-like) objects.

Comment: @Stef, i've tried that, but somehow only the default single.php (read: else) is shown. I will try again with  !is_page and get back to you.

Comment: @Stef I tried different variatons of `is_page` and `!is_page`. Maybe it's because I'm loading posts dynamically on a div?

Comment: I don't know Andre, but looks like you accepted an answer so I hope you figured it out. Lots of luck with your website!